# Do I need to declare (& how) this firebase object example or may just call it?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

Trying to implement this firebase example on angular:-

```
function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
username: name,
email: email,
profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
}
```

**Question:**

What about **firebase** object? Do I need to declare it? How?

If I use it like in the example, I got this console error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined

But I just can't make it works, I guess it must be declared just don't know what type or the correct way to do...

PS. Im using angularfire2 and imported as:

`import { AngularFireList, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database'`;

Comment: are you using angularfire? https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularfire2

Comment: yes and importend as: import { AngularFireList, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database'

Comment: share your code in stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is native Javascript SDK way, in order to work that way you need to import `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';`

The Angularfire2 way

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
```

declare a reference `itemsRef: AngularFireList<any>;` inside appcomponent

then inject `AngularFireDatabase` to your constructor

```
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.itemsRef = db.list('users');
}
```

now in function look like this

```
function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
    this.itemsRef.update(userId,{
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
}
```

Check the example [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#deleting-the-entire-list)

Comment: It worked on the first try! Thank you very much Hareesh

Answer (score 0):

To access the Firebase database object, inject `AngularFireDatabase`:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.db.database.ref(...);
}
```